# Is Civic Duty Badge supposed to be shown in review section

Tags: discussion

I just noticed [Civic Duty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty) badge in `Badge Progress` bar of review section.

[image: screenshot]

The [tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty) says

> Voted 300 or more times.

If i understood correctly, All other badges mentioned in the list can be achieved by the actions in review section - Approve, Reject & Improve.

Since we're note voting directly from review section (*as far as i know*)

Does it actually belong there..?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Civic Duty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty) and [Electorate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/155/electorate) badges both relate to voting.

While you can't vote in the [Suggested Edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/) queue, you can certainly vote in all of the other queues, which is why your progress for those badges is shown there.

Voting and flagging are particularly important in the [First Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) and [Late Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers) sections because they help new users understand how to ask better questions and write better answers.

I suppose you could hide them in the Suggested Edits' progress menu, but there's not much of a point to that.

Comment: oops. my mistake i didn't check the reviews section. will accept the answer once the system allows...